# Adding tooltips to a d3 bar graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is my first post here I have searched the forum but still cant seem to get the tootips to work correctly on my bargraph.  For some reason the variables that i input into the .html are showing up undefined in the tooltip text.

also here is link to my codepen:

https://codepen.io/CraigMarc/pen/YzOGbXW?editors=0110

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET",'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json', true);
req.send();
req.onload=function(){
const json = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
 
 
  let parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
  

 
 
 let tooltip = d3
      .select("body")
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .attr("id", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);

  
  
  
 const w = 1000;
const h = 400;
  const padding = 40;
  
  const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
             .domain([d3.min(json.data, (d) => parseTime(d[0])), d3.max(json.data, (d) => parseTime(d[0]))])
             .range([padding, w - padding])
  
  console.log(d3.max(json.data, (d) => parseTime(d[0])))
  
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear([0 , d3.max(json.data, (d) => d[1])])

.domain([0 , d3.max(json.data, (d) => d[1])])
.range([0 , h - (2 * padding)]);
  
  
const svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h);
  
svg.selectAll("rect")
.data(json.data)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(parseTime(d[0])))
.attr("y", (d, i) =>  (h-padding) - yScale(d[1]))
.attr("width", (d) => w / json.data.length)
.attr("height", (d, i) => yScale(d[1]))
.attr("fill", "navy")
.attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("data-date", (d) => d[0])
  .attr("data-gdp", (d) => d[1])
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        tooltip
          .transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", 0.9);
        tooltip
          .html("$ " + d[0])
          .style("left", d3.event.pageX + 20 + "px")
          .style("top", d3.event.pageY + 20 + "px");
        tooltip.attr("data-date", d[0]);
      })
  
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    tooltip.attr("data-date", d[0]);
        tooltip
          .transition()
          .duration(400)
          .style("opacity", 0);})
  
  
  
  
  
  
 const yAxisScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                 .domain([0, d3.max(json.data, (d) => d[1])])
                 .range([h - padding, padding]);
 
 const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yAxisScale);
 const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
 
  svg.append("g")
  .attr("id", "y-axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + (padding) + ",0)")
.call(yAxis);

  
  svg.append("g")
  .attr("id", "x-axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
     .call(xAxis)

}
});


CSS

#tooltip 
{   
    position: absolute;         
    text-align: center;         
    width: 60px;                    
    height: auto;                   
    padding: 2px;               
    font: 12px sans-serif;      
    background: lavender;   
    border: 0px;        
    border-radius: 8px;         
    pointer-events: none;           
}
```

Comment: The datum has to be the second parameter: `.on("mouseover", function(event,d) {`.

Comment: codepen link is not working

Comment: i ended up getting it working here is an updated link   https://codepen.io/CraigMarc/pen/bGxBWQx

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out i needed two attributes in the mouseover function (e, d)